# Unable to loacte "Configure databricks" in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2010, databricks, cluster-computing

Need help in locating "configure databricks" option to connect to a cluster in visual studio code.
Not sure which settings need to enabled to view/access the configuration. Below is the screen shot of it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeMXC.png)

Try on enable some the settings, it doesn't work.

Comment: what happens if you open a folder using that button? does the view change and add the "configure databricks" button?